# IIS Express tries to open file in its own folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I'm working on an existing VS2013 Express ASP.NET (C#) application.
I'm trying to get it to run on my local machine.

My application tries to open a pdf file which is in de source folder of my application (my *.cs files and the pfd are in the same location).

The application tries to open the pdf and send it to the browser:

```
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open("test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
            fs.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

This doesn't work because IIS tries to open this file:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\test.pdf
```

The file does not exists on that location.

This is most likely an issue of my IIS Express configuration because we don't have the problems on other dev machines and I have a similar issue with another application.

I've been searching and reading for hours now but can't find how to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Have you tried adding Server.MapPath() around the filename to select the web root?

Comment: You should *always* use `Server.MapPath()`. Unqualified paths are a very bad idea in a hosted environment. So use `File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/test.pdf"), FileMode.Open)` instead.

Comment: Thanks all. I've spoken to our lead developer and we've changed the code. I'm now using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/");